# Para que o os.environ.setdefault() do Django serve?

Tags: python, django

Estou estudando mais sobre o Django e celery e me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código ao ter que configurar o celery no projeto.

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings') 

app = Celery('my_app') 
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY') 
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Eu entendi a maior parte do código porém não consegui entender o que o método os.environ.setdefault() faz , também não entendi o que é esse DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (primeiro argumento que é passado).

Então queria saber o que é esse DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE? Por que ele é passo como argumento para DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE? O que o DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE está fazendo?

Comment: `os.environ.setdefault` faz o mesmo que [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) (como você pode ver no [código fonte do CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/os.py#L714)). Em resumo `dict.setdefault(CHAVE, VALOR)` retorna o que tiver em `dict[CHAVE]` se não houver nada é criado `dict[CHAVE] = VALOR` e então é retornado `VALOR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação de settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/) do Django, a variável de ambiente **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** serve para definir qual será o settings default do seu projeto.

Qualquer comando que você faça do Django no seu terminal, requer que um arquivo de settings seja acessado. Quando você tem configurado esta variável de ambiente, não é necessário mencionar o settings no comando do terminal.

Por exemplo, quando eu rodo:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost
```

E tenho minha variável **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** definida como **my_app.settings** ele automaticamente acessará o arquivo no caminho **my_app/settings.py** do seu projeto.

Se você quiser em ocasiões específicas acessar o projeto com settings diferentes, pode criar um novo arquivo de settings, como por exemplo no caminho **my_app/homolog.py**, você pode ocasionalmente rodar os comandos com essa configuração utilizando:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost --settings=my_app.homolog
```

A variável **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** será sobrescrita e será atribuído como configuração a este comando específico o arquivo **my_app/homolog.py**.